# how to subset a list where certain column does not contain

Tags: r

```
$DANN_score
   label  Predictor label
79     0 DANN_score 0.999
80     0 DANN_score     .
81     0 DANN_score 0.934
82     0 DANN_score 0.543
83     0 DANN_score     .
84     0 DANN_score     .

$fathmm.MKL_coding_score
   label               Predictor label
85     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score 0.977
86     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score     .
87     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score 0.147
88     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score 0.089
89     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score     .
90     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score     .
```

where I would like to remove elements where `label` = '.' i.e. missing data.

I only know how to do this with a dataframe (which I do not want to convert to) i.e. something like

```
subset(df,df[3] != '.')
```

so how can I do this with a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` with `lapply` and subset the rows based on the third column

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[x[[3]]!=".",])
#$DANN_score
#   label  Predictor label
#79     0 DANN_score 0.999
#81     0 DANN_score 0.934
#82     0 DANN_score 0.543

#$fathmm.MKL_coding_score
#   label               Predictor label
#85     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score 0.977
#87     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score 0.147
#88     0 fathmm.MKL_coding_score 0.089
```

#### data

```
lst <- structure(list(DANN_score = structure(list(label = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Predictor = c("DANN_score", "DANN_score", "DANN_score", 
"DANN_score", "DANN_score", "DANN_score"), label = c("0.999", 
".", "0.934", "0.543", ".", ".")), .Names = c("label", "Predictor", 
"label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84")), fathmm.MKL_coding_score = structure(list(
    label = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Predictor = c("fathmm.MKL_coding_score", 
    "fathmm.MKL_coding_score", "fathmm.MKL_coding_score", "fathmm.MKL_coding_score", 
    "fathmm.MKL_coding_score", "fathmm.MKL_coding_score"), label = c("0.977", 
    ".", "0.147", "0.089", ".", ".")), .Names = c("label", "Predictor", 
"label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("85", "86", "87", 
"88", "89", "90"))), .Names = c("DANN_score", "fathmm.MKL_coding_score"
))
```